# Can the nested Dll's be used with only one refrence

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

[image: The Design used]
in the above deign there is an issue where in i need to add the reference to the (1)DLL in my sample application to get the usercontrol , is there a way to embed the dll(1) inside dll(2) so that i need to only add reference  to the DLl2 in my application

Comment: if you follow that logic to its conclusion, why have any DLLs, embed everything into the .exe?

Comment: Actually i want to create the dll2 extending the functionality  that exists in dll1 so that the dll1 can be used across application's, so exe is not an option for me

Comment: so why is having 2 DLL's a problem?

Comment: the main reason for creating the 2nd dll is  to act as a wrapper over the 1st and expose more functionality , so i don't think it right to have reference to both the dll's

Answer (score 0):

If you create a component DLL project (DLL2) and reference DLL1, it will be copied into a project that references this WinRT component without having to explictly reference DLL1.

Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes but since the dll 1 has a user control my sample application does not seem to  work unless i add a direct reference of the dll1 in the sample project